# Biliography setting TexStudio Ubuntu

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texstudio, ubuntu, linux

I want to sort my bibliography in ascending order. I want to list my references in arrange alphabetically. MY  Bibliography code is:

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
% This specifies the location of the file containing the bibliographic information.
\cleardoublepage % This is needed if the book class is used, to place the anchor in the correct page,
                 % because the bibliography will start on its own page.
                 % Use \clearpage instead if the document class uses the "oneside" argument
\phantomsection  % With hyperref package, enables hyperlinking from the table of contents to bibliography
% The following statement causes the title "References" to be used for the bibliography section:
\renewcommand*{\bibname}{References}

% Add the References to the Table of Contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{References}}

\bibliography{mybib}
\nocite{*}
```

the bibliography displayed in this style:
[image: Refrences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkcFk.png)!]
But i want that reference number 4 should be at number 1 then second should displayed so in this manner they sort alphabetically. Please help me

Comment: It seems like your bibliography is already sorted alphabetically considering the last names of the first authors. Rarely first name is used for sorting since citations mostly use the last name. If you still want to sort wrt first name, the style may have options for that.

Comment: Ubuntu, texstudio and  linux have nothing to do with your question

Comment: If you just want to move *Boneh et. al* to the begin, try to add `@PREAMBLE{ {\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}} }` to your bib file and replace `Boneh` with `{{\noopsort{aaaaaaaaBoneh}}{Boneh}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your questions, but if you just want to move Boneh et. al to the begin, try to add `@PREAMBLE{ {\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}} }` to your bib file and replace `Boneh` with `{{\noopsort{aaaaaaaaBoneh}}{Boneh}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@PREAMBLE{ {\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}} }

@article{reese,
  author       = {Reese, Trevor R.},
  title        = {Georgia in {Anglo-Spanish} Diplomacy, 1736--1739},
  journaltitle = {William and Mary Quarterly},
  year         = 1958,
  series       = 3,
  volume       = 15,
  pages        = {168-190},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  annotation   = {An \texttt{article} entry with a \texttt{series} and a
                  \texttt{volume} field. Note the format of the series. If the
                  value of the \texttt{series} field is an integer, this number
                  is printed as an ordinal and the string \enquote*{series} is
                  appended automatically},
}

@article{sarfraz,
  author       = {M. {{\noopsort{aaaaaaaaSarfraz}}{Sarfraz}} and M. F. A. Razzak},
  title        = {Technical section: {An} algorithm for automatic capturing of
                  the font outlines},
  year         = 2002,
  volume       = 26,
  number       = 5,
  pages        = {795-804},
  issn         = {0097-8493},
  journal      = {Computers and Graphics},
  annotation   = {An \texttt{article} entry with an \texttt{issn} field},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\cite{sarfraz,reese}

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your Code `{{\noopsort{aaaaaaaaBoneh}}{Boneh}}`  is not working :(

Comment: @sam please provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that demonstrates your problem